# Pagination of data issue: java + oracle sql

Tags: java, oracle, pagination

I have a requirement for pagination of data(items) retrieved from database.
The UI also contains search options and the amount of data, order also depends on search criteria.

Let's say a client send request for with some search criteria and gets 60 results. The client see the items from 1 to maxPageSize (25 by default). If 2nd page is requested - 26-50 items will be shown.
The problem is on current moment I can't get amount of max results and can't display number of maxPage.

I see 2 solutions for this problem:

1. Query database second time with the same parameters but without
   pagination and get count of the items.
2. Retrieve all items from DB,
   filter them on backend code by search criteria and send to client.

The questions are:

**1) Which of the operations is less expensive in general?**

**2) What else can be done to solve this kind of task if there is better solution?**

P.S. the backend code written on Java, queries send via JDBC to Oracle 11g DB.

**---EDIT---**

I've solved this problem this way:

```
WITH FINAL_RESULT AS 
    (SELECT SORTED_ITEMS.*, 
            ROWNUM RN 
     FROM (sorted basic query with searches))

   SELECT FINAL_RESULT.*, 
         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM FINAL_RESULT) ITEMS_COUNT
    FROM FINAL_RESULT
    WHERE RN BETWEEN ? AND ?
```

Comment: Why can't you get the total number of results?  But what's more, why do you even need it?  Just query for 26 results, and if you get back 26 then make the next button visible, otherwise grey it out.

Comment: The design on the FE requires pagination like 1, 2, 3 ... 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second solution would be quite expensive in case there is bulk amount of data in the Database.

However, the First solution is quite suitable with some tweeks in it. You don't need to Query database second time with the same parameters, instead the server should send the TOTAL_COUNT in each request and the value should be cached.

If the count hasn't changed, there would be no load to the Database because of caching.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your statement "If the count hasn't changed, there would be no load to the Database because of caching"

Comment: If any necessary edits are required, the answer is open to them :)